# SqlAlchemy: hybrid attribute as sum of columns with null values

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I've got a simple problem I can't figure out.

I've got a simple data model with three integer columns (which can be null). I want to create an hybrid attribute to get the sum of three columns. My wish is to finally get the maximal total or to filter according to this total.

I've made a minimal example.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
"""The database engine."""

DbSession = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
"""The application session class."""


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    """The SQLalchemy declarative base."""


class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    x: Mapped[int | None]
    y: Mapped[int | None]
    z: Mapped[int | None]

    @hybrid_property
    def total(self):
        return self.x + self.y + self.z

    @total.expression
    @classmethod
    def total(cls):
        return select(cls.x + cls.y + cls.z).label("total")


@contextmanager
def get_db() -> DbSession:
    """Return a database session."""
    with DbSession() as db_is:
        with db_is.begin():
            yield db_is
        # inner context calls db.commit(), if there were no exceptions
    # outer context calls db.close()


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with get_db() as db:
    # Add data
    db.add(Data(x=1, y=1, z=None))
    db.add(Data(x=None, y=2, z=2))
    db.add(Data(x=3, y=3, z=3))
    db.flush()

    # Try to get maximal total
    print(db.scalar(select(func.max(Data.total))))

    # Try to get entries with total less than 5
    print(db.scalars(select(Data).filter(Data.total < 5)).all())
```

My problems are:

- It seems something goes wrong in the hybrid attribute definition in case of None value in x, y and z columns. Should I use a case?
- Even my two final request instructions seem buggy.

The above code fails. The first statement `db.scalar(select(func.max(Data.total)))` fails with the following message.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) misuse of aggregate: max()
[SQL: SELECT max((SELECT data.x + data.y + data.z AS anon_1 
FROM data)) AS max_1]
```

The second statement `db.scalars(select(Data).filter(Data.total < 5)).all()` returns `[]`. Running `db.scalars(select(Data.total)).all()` returns `[None]`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: "something goes wrong " - how it doesn't work?

Comment: Edited ! Sorry :(

Comment: Try to rename the 2nd `total` definition to `_total_expression`

Comment: Using `db.scalars(select(Data.total)).all()` gives me `[None, None, 9]` now. Remains the problem with null values.

Comment: the `_total_expression` function name is OK if I use `@total.inplace.expression`. Here, using something else than simply `total` made sqlalchemy use the pythonic whiting of total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem.

The problem comes from my total expression. Instead of writing

```py
    @total.expression
    @classmethod
    def total(cls):
        return select(cls.x + cls.y + cls.z).label("total")
```

I need to write

```py
    @total.expression
    @classmethod
    def total(cls):
        return cls.x + cls.y + cls.z
```

The select and label are NOT necessary. Yet, this is a mystery for me as I use such pattern for other cases I need to agregate. Maybe this is linked to a subrequest matter.

In addition, the NULL problem is resolved using the `coalesce` function. One more fix for Pythonic expression gives me:

```py
class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = "data"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    x: Mapped[int | None]
    y: Mapped[int | None]
    z: Mapped[int | None]

    @hybrid_property
    def total(self):
        return (self.x or 0) + (self.y or 0) + (self.z or 0)

    @total.expression
    @classmethod
    def total(cls):
        return func.coalesce(cls.x, 0) + func.coalesce(cls.y, 0) + func.coalesce(cls.z, 0)
```

That's the answer :)